# How can i create a restangular service to update data

Tags: angular, symfony, restangular

Hello I'm trying to create a service with **restangular** to update data

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Project} from '../model/index';
import {id} from '@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/utils';
import {Restangular} from 'ngx-restangular';

@Injectable()
export class updateprojectService {
constructor (private restangular: Restangular) {}
update(project: Project) {
    return this.restangular.all('projects').customPUT(project,  {'id': project.id}, undefined, {'Content-Type': undefined});
}
}
```

and I found this error
[image]

Maybe the error is to specify the id in route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building that put URL someway wrong, notice last part of it `/[object%20Object]` that's how javascript print an object reference.

I believe it was supposed to be an id, so it would be `/projects/55` for example.

Accordingly to restangular documentation, `customPUT([elem, path, params, headers])`, second param is a path, that's why you are getting that problem, you are passing an object to a path

change `{'id': project.id}` to `project.id` if you would like to have an url like `/projects/55`